# Is there a way to access package-private String.isLatin1() from java.util package using jdk.internal.access.SharedSecrets?

Tags: java, unsafe

I'm trying to access `String.isLatin1()` which is declared (as of JDK 14) as

```java
boolean isLatin1() {
    return COMPACT_STRINGS && coder == LATIN1;
}
```

I can do this with reflection

```java
Method isLatin1 = String.class.getDeclaredMethod("isLatin1");
isLatin1.setAccessible(true);
isLatin1.invoke(""); //true
```

but I wonder whether I can do the same with `SharedSecrets`?

I've tried

```java
SharedSecrets.getJavaLangAccess().getDeclaredPublicMethods(String.class, "isLatin1");
```

but for obvious reason it returns an empty list. Also I've tried to utilize `jdk.internal.access.JavaLangReflectAccess` available from `SharedSecredts`, but it doesn't have any suitable method.

Comment: Instead of trying to hack the String class, why not use `s.codePoints().allMatch(c -> c < 256)`?

Comment: @VGR I suppose `String.codePoints()` has O(n) complexity e.g. the longer String we have the more code points must be checked in general case. And unlike `String.codePoints()` `String.isLatin1()` has O(1) complexity.

Comment: Comparing a series of 32-bit values to a constant is a pretty fast operation.  Are you sure this is something that needs to be optimized?

Comment: @VGR Comparing is executed with Stream API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not going to work.  The shared secrets mechanism provides a way to *specific* package private methods.  If you look at the source code, you will see that there is an "access" interface that exposes a fixed set of methods.  The shared secrets interface for the `java.lang` package exposes some methods for getting a string's internal byte array without copying it.  But it doesn't provide a method that does what you want.

Furthermore, the `isLatin1()` method that you are trying to access is `private` rather than package private, so it cannot be exposed anyway ... unless you change that.

In short, you can't use `SharedSecrets` for this unless you are prepared to *modify the OpenJDK source code and build your own JVM*.  It might be acceptable to do that as an experiment, but there are lots of red flags for production use.

Use reflection.  It is more practical ... modulo that you risk causing future portability problems for your application.  (Consider that the internal representation of `String` have changed 2 or 3 times *so far* since Java 1.1.  It could happen again.)

Comment: You are right, it turned out that in this case particular functionality must be added to `SharedSecrets`.

Answer (score 1):

At last replace old reflect solution to transformed of @VGR

```
static boolean isLatin(String s) {
    return s.codePoints().allMatch(ch -> (ch & 0xFF00) == 0);
}
```